How can I save a ggplot within Azure Synapse?
I'm trying to save a ggplot that I created in a Synapse Analytics notebook in R.
I found a previous question explaining what to do in Python, but I can't replicate it in R.
I successfully mounted the Azure Blob Storage account using mssparkutils.fs.mount() and am able to see into the account using mssparkutils.fs.ls(). However, when I try to use ggsave() to save the plot to file:/{mount_path}/local/..., I don't see the file at the specified path.
In the notebook itself, I only see a message "Saving 6.67 x 6.67 in image".
I'm a little new at this, so apologies if I used the wrong terms.

Please add error you are facing

I don’t get a specific error, the image just fails to save.

I have tried the below approach in matplotlib for plotting and saving images:
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
"abfss://rawcontainer@lambostg.dfs.core.windows.net", 
    "/mnt", 
    { "linkedService": "synpsilip-WorkspaceDefaultStorage" }
)
mssparkutils.fs.mkdirs("/mnt/folder02")
local_plot_path = "/tmp/sample_plot.png"
plt.savefig(local_plot_path)
print(f"Plot saved locally at: {local_plot_path}")
dest_plot_path = "/mnt/folder02/sample_plot.png"
mssparkutils.fs.cp(f"file://{local_plot_path}", f"abfss://rawcontainer@lambostg.dfs.core.windows.net/folder02/sample_plot.png")
print(f"Plot copied to: {dest_plot_path} in Blob Storage")
files = mssparkutils.fs.ls("/mnt/folder02")
for file in files:
    print(file.name)

In the above code mounting the Azure Blob Storage & Creating the directory
Saving the plot locally and Copying the file to the mounted Azure Blob Storage Listing files in the directory to verify
Results:
/mnt
Plot saved locally at: /tmp/sample_plot.png
Plot copied to: /mnt/folder02/sample_plot.png in Blob Storage



This came really close, but I had to add the working directory in front of the local path for mssparkutils to recognize the locally-saved plot! Thanks.
